# Repeating HTML, minus a few class and array key differences

Tags: php, laravel

I feel like this code is pretty sloppy and can be accomplished in a `foreach` loop. But it's a bit complex using a multi-dimensional array.

Can this be cleaner? You can see I'm repeating much of the same code in each `li`, minus some class and array key differences, etc. Should this be a `foreach` loop? What's the best approach?

```
// data example:
{
    "user": {
        "assigned": 3,
        "overdue": 2,
        "in_review": 1,
        "in_progress": 2
    },
    "team_avg": {
        "overdue": 1,
        "in_review": 1,
        "in_progress": 1,
        "assigned": 1
    }
}

<ul class="large-block-grid-4">
    <li>
        <small>Assigned</small>
        <h4 class="assigned">
            {{ AbbrNum::convert($taskload['user']['assigned']) }}
            @if (count($taskload['team_avg']))
                @if ($taskload['user']['assigned'] > $taskload['team_avg']['assigned'])
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Above Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-up above-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @elseif ($taskload['user']['assigned'] == $taskload['team_avg']['assigned'])
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @else
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-down below-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @endif
            @endif
        </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <small>In Progress</small>
        <h4 class="in-progress">
            {{ AbbrNum::convert($taskload['user']['in_progress']) }}
            @if (count($taskload['team_avg']))
                @if ($taskload['user']['in_progress'] > $taskload['team_avg']['in_progress'])
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Above Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-up above-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @elseif ($taskload['user']['in_progress'] == $taskload['team_avg']['in_progress'])
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @else
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-down below-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @endif
            @endif
        </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <small>In Review</small>
        <h4 class="in-review">
            {{ AbbrNum::convert($taskload['user']['in_review']) }}
            @if (count($taskload['team_avg']))
                @if ($taskload['user']['in_review'] > $taskload['team_avg']['in_review'])
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Above Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-up above-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @elseif ($taskload['user']['in_review'] == $taskload['team_avg']['in_review'])
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @else
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-down below-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @endif
            @endif
        </h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <small>Overdue</small>
        <h4 class="overdue">
            {{ AbbrNum::convert($taskload['user']['overdue']) }}
            @if (count($taskload['team_avg']))
                @if ($taskload['user']['overdue'] > $taskload['team_avg']['overdue'])
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Above Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-up below-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @elseif ($taskload['user']['overdue'] == $taskload['team_avg']['overdue'])
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @else
                    <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-down above-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                @endif
            @endif
        </h4>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/126535/edit) your title to say something about what the code does rather than what you'd like reviewed.

Comment: The title still doesn't look proper.  Please look at the front page for examples on good titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that a `foreach` would be possible, but probably not the best solution here as it would indeed make the code overly complex. There is a lot of repetition though, so there is indeed room for improvement. I think a partial sub view would probably be the cleanest solution here. This is how I would go about it.

in a separate file (partials/list_item.blade.php):

```
<li>
    <small>{{$title}}</small>
    <h4 class="{{$class}}">
        {{ AbbrNum::convert($taskload['user'][$type]) }}
        @if (count($taskload['team_avg']))
            @if ($taskload['user'][$type] > $taskload['team_avg'][$type])
                <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Above Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-up above-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            @elseif ($taskload['user'][$type] == $taskload['team_avg'][$type])
                <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            @else
                <i data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" title="Below Team Avg" class="fa fa-arrow-down below-avg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            @endif
        @endif
    </h4>
</li>
```

And in your existing template:

```
<ul class="large-block-grid-4">
    @include('partials.list_item', ['title' => 'Assigned', 'type' => 'assigned', 'class' => 'assigned' ])
    @include('partials.list_item', ['title' => 'In progress', 'type' => 'in_progress', 'class' => 'in-progress' ])
    ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting concept! I didn't think to approach it like this - but makes sense. I wonder if there's any performance differences between this and a `foreach`. That said, if there is, it's likely very low/petty anyways. Thanks for your feedback/help!

Comment: What about foreach'ing the partial?

Comment: Wait, that's essentially the same thing as my original question lol